# SQL Select single row based on multiple values

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table that looks like the following

```
id, in_use
1, T
1, F
2, T
2, T
3, F
```

I'm trying to write a sql query that has the logic "If one ID has 'T' and 'F', return 'T'" gives the output as the following

```
id, in_use
1, T
2, T
3, F
```

I believe I should be doing some sort of aggregation function, but I can't figure out how to get the logic of collapsing two rows into one. Any tips?

Comment: From what i've understood you need to check DISTINCT and how it works. In order for somebody to show you how to use it, we would need you to give us sample code and the results you are getting from the sample code. Also, please tag what type of sql you are using - sql-server, mysql and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As T is Bigger than F( as characters or Ascii ) T will always return if one id has it, only if all rows of one id are F it will return F

```
SELECT
    id, MAX(in_use) as in_use
FROM mytable
GROUP BY id
```